# How can I delete a cookie in a particular page?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am creating a cookie in one page of an ASP.NET application and I want to delete it in another page. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Microsoft:  How To Delete a Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx)

You cannot directly delete a cookie on a user's computer. However, you can direct the user's browser to delete the cookie by setting the cookie's expiration date to a past date. The next time a user makes a request to a page within the domain or path that set the cookie, the browser will determine that the cookie has expired and remove it.

To assign a past expiration date on a cookie

1. Determine whether the cookie exists in the request, and if so, create a new cookie with the same name.
2. Set the cookie's expiration date to a time in the past.
3. Add the cookie to the Cookies collection object of the Response.

The following code example shows how to set a past expiration date on a cookie.

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Note:  Calling the Remove method of the Cookies collection removes the cookie from the collection on the server side, so the cookie will not be sent to the client. However, the method does not remove the cookie from the client if it already exists there.

Comment: What about a session cookie ( i.e. `Expires` has never been set) ? After calling the `Remove` method, when is it completely removed? In a page cycle, when should I call remove for this to affect the client immediately?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried expiring your cookie?

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies["cookie_name"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Delete a Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx)

```
if (Request.Cookies["MyCookie"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set the expiry date of the cookie to a previous date.

For Example :

```
  HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie("newCookie");
  newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
  Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
```

Now only doing this will not be helpful as the cookie will not be physically removed. You have to remove the cookie.

```
  if (newCookie.Expires < DateTime.Now)
        {
            Request.Cookies.Remove("newCookie");
        }
```

Here you go. This applies to any page within the solution.